# Nodejs Rest API : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: News.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I seem to keep getting the error when I hit the news api

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: News.find is not a function

[image]

I read up on Promises but could not solve this. Is this a mongoose thing?
How should I solve this?

My controller ***NewsController.js***

```
const NewsController = {};
const News = require('../models/news.model');

// await indicates wait for the function to get over.
// we may also use Promises in its place
NewsController.getNews = async function(req, res) {
    const allnews = await News.find({}, function(err, ns) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            res.json(ns);
        });
      //res.json(allnews);

  };
  // ES6 style
  NewsController.getSingleNews = async (req, res) => {

      const news = await News.findById(req.params.Id);
      res.json[news];
    };
    NewsController.createNews = async (req, res) => {
        const news = new News(req.body);
        await news.save();

        res.json[{
          'status': 'item saved successfully'
        }];
      };

      NewsController.deleteNews = async (req, res) => {
        await News.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
        res.json[{
          'status': 'item deleted successfully'
        }]
      };

module.exports = NewsController;
```

My model ***news.model.js***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const {Schema}= mongoose;
const newsSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String, required:true},
  content:{type: String, required:true},
  author:{type: String},
  image:{type: String},
  source:{type: String}
});

mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('news', newsSchema);
```

Comment: Is `.find()` a `static` method of `News` class? Why is `const news = new News(req.body)` used at one portion of the code but not before `const allnews = await News.find({}, function(){})`?

Comment: `module.exports` not `mongoose.exports`

Comment: @guest271314 The new is used because it is the create/post method.  As for the const, i could have used var. .find is a function offered by the mongoose module..so i will need to check that.

Comment: Why does `News` require using `new News()` in one part of code, though not in the other? Is `News` a `class`? What does `console.log(News)` print before `News.find()` is reached?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: oops and thanks! It works now.  What debugger should do you recommend?

Comment: No debugger you have just made a minor mistake or typo here

Answer (score 0):

The issue was mongoose.exports. It should have been module.exports Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet

Answer (score 0):

please look at your script. You've got error because your code didn't have function find. Create it and try again.